# How to use distinct per day?

Tags: sqlite

I have some data in SQLite database.

Scheme: `ID | MSG | DATE /datetime`

My question is, how can I select the count of items per day

Like this:

```
06-26-2019: 6
06-27-2019: 10
```

I am able to write single distinct without count, can you help me to create full SQL please?

```
SELECT distinct(strftime('%d-%m-%Y', date)) 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using simple `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', DATE)`

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', DATE), COUNT(*) AS DateCount
FROM table
GROUP BY STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', DATE)
```